# kubernetes pod does not use space even when there is space on the node

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a zookeeper pod that somehow went to Crashloopbackoff and now no matter what I do , it is not coming up even though there is enough space on the node.

Remaining space in node : 46G

Space requested by my pod : 2000Mi

I am able to see this in the logs of the pod

===> Configuring ...
[Errno 28] No space left on device
Command [/usr/local/bin/dub template /etc/confluent/docker/myid.template /var/lib/zookeeper/data/myid] FAILED !

I have tried

```
kubectl delete pod zookeeper
```

after which it just goes back to crashloopbackoff

Is there anyway to recover the pod(statefulset) without terminating and redeploying ?

Please help.

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason here but some space on the file system is reserved for root (typically 5%).

Comment: Hmm , Yes . But if that was causing the issue , it should not come up even when I terminate and redeploy the pod right ?

Comment: Another reason could be that you have run out of inodes on the filesystem (I think the error message is the same in that case, but I may be wrong). Can you log in on the node and check if you can create a file manually?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor , No progress issue wise. The pods are still not coming up.

I found a workound though . If I change the replicaset of the statefulset and upgrade the statefulset as a whole , the zookeeper pods are coming up as intended.

Comment: @darthsithius I see. Could you please try using `docker image prune -f` and/or `docker container prune -f`? These would remove unused data and free some disc space.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with leftover docker images. You should check:

- available space with `df -h`
- available inodes with `df -i`

The most common solution for this issue is to [remove unused docker images](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-images) with `docker image prune -a`:

```
WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
```

You can also use `docker system prune` that would delete all containers that were stopped as well as all volumes and networks and that are not used by any container. It will also remove all dangling images.

Comment: Since I no longer have the setup to check this , I cannot confirm. As I said in an earlier comment , I changed the replicaset. On running into a further issue , I terminated the release and redelpoyed it.